# How to apply click event for option button using Zend form

Tags: zend-framework

I am new to zend, Below is my piece of code,

```
    $TEST   = new Zend_Form_Element_Radio('test', array(
        'label' => 'Send:*',
        'value' => $data,
        'multiOptions' => array(0 => 'TEST1', 1 => 'TEST2',2 => 'TEST3 '),
    ));
        $this->addElement($TEST);
```

Here i Want to apply onclick event for above 3 option button respectively.Is it possible ?.Kindly help me on this

Comment: You mean, how to do it in JavaScript?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would probably be best off using jQuery for this?  E.g.:

```
$(function() {
    $("#test").click(function(){
        // whatever you need to do 
    });
});
```